# ILSpy assembly reference missing

Tags: .net-assembly, ilspy

I have a project "A", which references 2 other projects "B" and "C".

For both references actual functions from these project are used in "A". 
But when I open the assembly A.dll with ILSpy, it only shows "B" and not "C" under references. 
If I remove the reference that is missing, my project no longer compiles, so it is in fact actually used.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The .dll will only contain an assembly reference if it uses types from the referenced assembly.
At compile-time it's possible that you need some additional assemblies.

Example:

C.dll:

```
class C { public void M1() {} }
```

B.dll:

```
class B : C { public void M2() {} }
```

A.dll:

```
class A {
   public static void Main() {
       new B().M2();
   }
}
```

When building `A.dll`, the compiler will require both B.dll and C.dll so that it can list all methods in type `B`.
However the resulting IL code will only reference class `B` and method `B.M2`, so the compiler does not need to emit an assembly reference to C.dll.